# Vue 3 - Composition API fetching data?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I am a bit confused with composition API and fetching data. When I open the page, I can see rendered list of categories, but if I want to use categories in setup(), it is undefined. How can I use categories value inside setup function? You can see that I want to console log categories.

**Category.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div class="page-container">
    <item
      v-for="(category, index) in categories"
      :key="index"
      :item="category"
      :is-selected="selectedItem === index"
      @click="selectItem(index)"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
import Item from '@/components/Item.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Item
  },

  setup () {
    const store = useStore()

    store.dispatch('categories/getCategories')

    const categories = computed(() => store.getters['categories/getCategories'])
    const selectedItem = ref(1)

    const selectItem = (index) => {
      selectedItem.value = index
    }
    
    console.log(categories.value[selectedItem.value].id)

    return {
      categories,
      selectedItem,
      selectItem
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import '@/assets/scss/general.scss';
</style>
```

**categories.js - vuex module**

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { API_URL } from '@/helpers/helpers'

export const categories = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    categories: []
  },

  getters: {
    getCategories: (state) => state.categories
  },

  mutations: {
    UPDATE_CATEGORIES: (state, newValue) => { state.categories = newValue }
  },

  actions: {
    async getCategories ({ commit }) {
      await axios.get(`${API_URL}/getCategories.php`).then(response => {
        commit('UPDATE_CATEGORIES', response.data.res_data.categories)
      })
    }
  },

  modules: {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the setup function you cannot process a computed function.
You can instead access **store.getters['categories/getCategories'].value[selectedItem.value].id** if you want to process that in the setup function.